# jQuery/Ajax call taking excruciating amount of time to complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

Below is jQuery code I'm using for their [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) plugin on my ASP MVC 3 view.

```
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Agent/GetAgents")';
                var agents = [];
                map = {};

                return ($.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        map[item.Name] = item;
                        agents.push(item.Name);
                    });

                    process(agents);
                }));
            },
            highlighter: function (item) {
                var p = map[item];
                var display = ''
                             + "<div class='typeahead_wrapper'>"
                             + "<div class='typeahead_labels'>"
                             + "<div class='typeahead_primary'>" + p.Name + </div>
                             + "<i>LastFour:</i>" + p.LastFour + "</div>"
                             + "<div class='typeahead_third'>" + "<i>Agent IDs:</i> " + p.AgentIds + "</div>"
                             + "</div>"
                             + "</div>";

                return display;
            },
            updater: function (item) {
                window.location.href = ("/Agent/Details/" + map[item].sNumber);                    
            }             
        });
```

The code calls this `GetAgents` method in the controller. The whole process compeletes as it is supposed to, but it takes almost a full minute to do so.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAgents(string term)
    {
        term = term.ToUpper();

        var agents = (from a in db.Agent
                      where a.FirstName.Contains(term) ||
                            a.LastName.Contains(term)
                      select a).AsEnumerable()
                             .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
                                 sNumber = x.sNumber,
                                 LastFour = x.DisplayTaxId,
                                 AgentIds = String.Join(", ", from b in db.sNumberToAgentId
                                                             where b.sNumber == x.sNumber
                                                             select b.AgentId)
                             });

        var corps = (from a in db.Agent
                      where a.CorporateName.Contains(term) 
                      select a).AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
                            sNumber = x.sNumber,
                            LastFour = x.DisplayTaxId,
                            AgentIds = String.Join(", ", from b in db.sNumberToAgentId
                                                         where b.sNumber == x.sNumber
                                                         select b.AgentId)
                        });

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = (agents.Union(corps).ToArray()),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

Stepping through the code, the trouble seems to be in this portion. Does anyone know a way to speed up a call such as this or why it is happening to begin with?

```
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = (agents.Union(corps).ToArray()),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
```

EDIT

I changed my queries to this strucutre below, however now I'm getting an `OutOfMemory Exception`

```
        var agents = (from a in db.Agent
                     from b in db.sNumberToAgentId
                     join b in db.sNumberToAgentId on a.sNumber equals b.sNumber into apm
                     where a.FirstName.Contains(term) || a.LastName.Contains(term)
                     select new
                                {
                                    Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                                    sNumber = a.sNumber,
                                    LastFour = a.DisplayTaxId,
                                    AgentIds = b.AgentId
                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Benchmark your SQL queries. The line `Data = (agents.Union(corps).ToArray())...` is what executes the queries, so it makes sense it's getting delayed there.

Comment: Why isn't one selection with `where a.FirstName.Contains(term) || a.LastName.Contains(term) || a.CorporateName.Contains(term)` sufficient?

Comment: I'm curious what sort of SQL this is generating and also why you're going from SQL syntax to constructor syntax (or whatever it's called) instead of doing it all in the latter and avoiding the AsEnumerable before doing your Select projection. I'm wondering if this format is causing the projection not to be applied in the SQL call but later evaluated meaning more data is coming back than necessary.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "benchmark" my SQL queries. If you mean compare to the rest that we do on this site, the wait time isn't even comparable. Most are complete within a matter of miliseconds but this take close to a full minute.

Comment: I think he means to take the generated SQL statement from this query and run it on your SQL DB to see how long it's taking to execute. The generated SQL would probably be enough to spot the problem, actually, but it couldn't hurt. They might be suggesting you need indexes, etc.

Comment: @ErikNoren: I thought this would be the best method to combine the results from two tables with a one-to-many relationship into one field and also use the `String.Join` method to style them w/a coma.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly given how likely this is to be reused, you might consider doing all this in a stored procedure and just calling it with your 'term' parameter.

If that's not feasible, I'd suggest you look to see if your data sources have many columns - your current syntax probably doesn't lend itself to optimized SQL. Usually your Select can be applied as a projection to only bring back columns from which you're pulling data.

You might try this but it's untested. I can't immediately think of the syntax for doing a join ahead of time to eliminate your subquery in the Select projection but maybe another person could help on that.

```
var results = db.Agent
  .Where(a => a.CorporateName.Contains(term) || a.FirstName.Contains(term) || a.LastName.Contains(term))
  .Select(x => new {
    Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
    sNumber = x.sNumber,
    LastFour = x.DisplayTaxId,
    AgentIds = String.Join(", ", from b in db.sNumberToAgentId
                                 where b.sNumber == x.sNumber
                                 select b.AgentId)
  });
```